# Polymorphic association in static metamodel JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity which contain polymorphic association to few entities. It definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notifications")
public class Notification implements java.io.Serializable {

//some fields ...

//Polymorphic association
@Any (metaColumn = @Column(name = "target_type"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "integer", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = Task.class, value = "Task"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = AdminNote.class, value = "AdminNote"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = UserCancelRequest.class, value = "UserCancelRequest"),
        //@MetaValue(targetEntity = TransferInfo.class, value = "TransferInfo"),
        //@MetaValue(targetEntity = NoteSubscription.class, value = "NoteSubscription")
})
@JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
@Getter
@Setter
private NotificationAssociation target;
```

My polymorphic association represented by interface NotificationAssociation:

```
public interface NotificationAssociation {
/**
 * Return actual type of associated entity
 * @return one of {@link NotificationTargetType}
 */
String getTargetType();

/**
 * Return associated entity id. Used in queries
 * @return target entity id
 */
Integer getTargetId();
}
```

And this works. But i need an access to *target* from *Notification* class in criteria though static metamodel API. My metamodel:

```
@StaticMetamodel(Notification.class)
public class Notification_ {
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Notification, Integer> id;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Notification, Integer>   postedById;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Notification, Integer> adminId;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Notification, NotificationAssociation> target;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Notification, Date> hiddenAt;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Notification, Date> createdAt;

}
```

In HQL/JPQL i can get access to it, 
but in metamodel *target* is null, and when i get model trough Root#getModel() a *target* isn't present in attributes list.
And my question is can i do so or there is any other solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you solved your problem but I recently faced the same issue.
And on my case I really needed to use CriteriaAPI since I had some generic processing for creating specifications.
Since HQL was not an option for me and we cannot mix HQL with specifications.
I fixed this issue by mapping the column twice. Using your example:

```
@Any (metaColumn = @Column(name = "target_type"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "integer", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = Task.class, value = "Task"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = AdminNote.class, value = "AdminNote"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = UserCancelRequest.class, value = "UserCancelRequest")
})
@JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
@Getter
@Setter
private NotificationAssociation target;

@Column(name = "target_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer targetId;
```

Doing that small tweak the metadata gets generated for targetId field and it becomes available on Criteria API. So then you can do something like:

```
notificationService.getAll((root, query, cb) -> cb.and(cb.equals(root.get("targetId"), someId), ...))
```

I hope this helps to anybody that is facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figure it out. An @Any annotation and related to it (@AnyMetadef and other) provides by Hibernate, not JPA. So we can't use JPA Criteria API to manage this kind of relations, but we can use Hibernate Criteria API instead.

Comment: Unfortunately also Hibernate Criteria API doesn't support this. This can be only done using HQL, eq. `from AuditLog log, Payment payment where log.item.class = 'Payment' and log.item.id = payment.id`. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where