# How to use @AnyMetaDef when using Spring JPA for polymorphic relationships

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, polymorphism

I'm trying to build a polymorphic relationship between tables and cannot seems to get it to work using @AnyMetaDef or @MetaValue.  It seems Spring JPA itself does not support these annotations but Hibernate annotations does.

The example I’m trying to setup is from here - [https://jpaobjects.sourceforge.net/m2-site/main/documentation/docbkx/html/user-guide/ch04s09.html#:~:text=A%20polymorphic%20relationship%20is%20one,any%20object%20in%20the%20database](https://jpaobjects.sourceforge.net/m2-site/main/documentation/docbkx/html/user-guide/ch04s09.html#:%7E:text=A%20polymorphic%20relationship%20is%20one,any%20object%20in%20the%20database).

The model should look like the below:

```
Users:
  id
  firstName
  
Companies:
  id
  companyName
  
Vehicles:
  id
  owner_id
  owner_type
  car_name
```

It’s not working for some reason and I believe this is because Spring JPA does not have the full hibernate annotations.

I’ve tried importing hibernate annotations separately in gradle but this didn't work

```
implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: '3.5.6-Final'
```

I’m obviously missing something.  Any support would be highly appreciated.

I also found this useful url

[Polymorphic association in static metamodel JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755831/polymorphic-association-in-static-metamodel-jpa/32761515#32761515)

Which explained it, but still have the same issue that I cannot seem to import the hibernate annotations for @AnyMetaDef on there.  I'm not sure if this has been deprecated, I haven't imported the right library, or there's else I need to setup.

-- UPDATE

After downloading the sourcecode of Hibernate core 6, I realised they deprecated the function

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html

```
One part of this work was the removal of various String-based approaches for specifying Types to use from annotations, including the removal of @AnyMetaDef, @AnyMetaDefs, @TypeDef and @TypeDefs, as well as removing annotation attributes accepting the type to use as a String (e.g. org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionType#type)
```

I'm still looking at solutions for this.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.